# Splash Screen: EXC_BAD_ACCESS after calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated delayed

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I am trying to create a 1-2 second splashcreen for my application using a modal view controller however when i try to dismiss the view my application crashes with a bad access error. So in my application delegate i have:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
 //create window and show it
 window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
 window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];


 //create the main view controller and add its view to the window 
 mainViewCtrl = [MainViewController alloc];
 [window addSubview:mainViewCtrl.view];


 //show splash screen
 UIImage *image      = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"default.png" ofType:nil]];
 splashViewCtrl  = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 splashViewCtrl.view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
 [mainViewCtrl presentModalViewController:splashViewCtrl animated:NO];

//setup callback to dismiss
[self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

return(true);
}

//hide splash screen callback
- (void)hideSplash {
 [[self mainViewCtrl] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And this all works perfectly fine except when the hideSplash is called after 2 seconds the application crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. If i comment out the perform selector line and call the hidesplash immediately after like so:

```
[mainViewCtrl presentModalViewController:splashViewCtrl animated:NO];

[self hideSplash];
```

The modal view is properly dismissed. I'm fairly sure this is a memory management problem but i'm not sure exacty what i'm doing wrong here. Does anyone have any ideas of what this could be or how to properly debug this so i can delay the dismissal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks weird:

```
mainViewCtrl = [MainViewController alloc];
```

Try adding the initialisation call to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
//show splash screen
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"default.png" ofType:nil]];
splashViewCtrl = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
splashViewCtrl.view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[mainViewCtrl presentModalViewController:splashViewCtrl animated:NO];
```

Change the above to this below:

```
//show splash screen
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"default.png" ofType:nil]];
splashViewCtrl = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
splashViewCtrl.view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[mainViewCtrl presentModalViewController:splashViewCtrl animated:NO];
[mainViewCtrl release]; //Add this line !!!!
```